# How to add Datatables buttons with language file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I try, but without success, to use my translation file with extraction buttons

Here is my code:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var table = $('#table').DataTable({
      "columnDefs": [{"orderable": false, "targets": 5}],
      "order": [1, "desc"],
      "oLanguage": { "sUrl": "/public/us.txt" },
      buttons: [{
        extend: 'csv',
        text: '<i class="fa fa-download"></i> Export to CSV',
        title: 'Data export - <?= date("YmdHi") ?>',
        className: 'btn-sm',
        exportOptions: { columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] }
      },{
        extend: 'excel',
        text: '<i class="fa fa-download"></i> Export to Excel',
        title: 'Data export - <?= date("YmdHi") ?>',
        className: 'btn-sm',
        exportOptions: { columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] }
      }]
    });
    table.buttons().container().appendTo( '.button-container' );
  });
```

The problem is when I add the line `"oLanguage": { "sUrl": "/public/us.txt" }` the buttons do not appear and I have no errors in the google console

**EDIT :**

**us.txt :**

```
{
    "sEmptyTable":     "No data available in table",
    "sInfo":           "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ entries",
    "sInfoEmpty":      "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries",
    "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtered from _MAX_ total entries)",
    "sInfoPostFix":    "",
    "sInfoThousands":  ",",
    "sLengthMenu":     "_MENU_ entries",
    "sLoadingRecords": "Loading...",
    "sProcessing":     "Processing...",
    "sSearch":         "",
    "searchPlaceholder": "Search ...",
    "sZeroRecords":    "No matching records found",
    "oPaginate": {
        "sFirst":    "First",
        "sLast":     "Last",
        "sNext":     "Next",
        "sPrevious": "Previous"
    },
    "oAria": {
        "sSortAscending":  ": activate to sort column ascending",
        "sSortDescending": ": activate to sort column descending"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show how is formated us.txt file? according to official documentation: All of the language information can be stored in a file on the server-side, which DataTables will look up if this parameter is passed. It must store the URL of the language file, which is in a JSON format, and the object has the same properties as the oLanguage object in the initialiser object (i.e. the above parameters). Please refer to one of the example language files to see how this works in action.

Comment: @Sigma I edited my post and added my file, I think the file is correct because it works (these are the buttons that do not appear) -- Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you please try to use just one parameter with oLanguage and see if the problem persist: use "oLanguage": {
        "sLengthMenu": "Show me just _MENU_ records"
      }, this changes the display length message, so to understand if the problem is including a json file for all parameters to personalize language or else.

Comment: The two references to change language I use (and has always worked) are https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/language.html and https://datatables.net/plug-ins/i18n/  I've used datatables for about 2 years on several projects and I've followed this (so I'm no 'expert' on different things) - I noticed you use 'oLanguage' which I've seen in older versions (I think) but never used, so I don't know if this is an issue - I only know that following the directions in the links has worked every time.  Hope it helps!

Comment: @Sigma CFP Support -  You may have found a track when I enter the language hard (without going through an url) everything works, the problem is that I can not do without an url (I have more language to manage and the link is dynamically modified according to users' session variables)

Comment: Reading the official documentation of DT seems there is another way to use different language string called Internationalisation and is explained here: https://datatables.net/plug-ins/i18n/ In the example is not used oLanguage (in fact is a little old but i was just adapted to the code the OP used in example). Please try this other method just using "language": {
                "url": "dataTables.german.lang"
            } Also you can use one of the translated lang json files or better pick up one and just modify with your strings without altering the structure at all and see if works.